# Datefield in Template in different language than english

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was trying to print DateField from a Model in my Template, but its in English, but i want it in different language (in my case Czech). Where is the problem? I have this in my settings.py, but its not working

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Prague'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'cs'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use this [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) in your template ?

Edit : Try to turn your variable "USE_I18N" to True in your settings.py, it should work.

Comment: Ok, I have made some tests, check my edit, don't use the filter

Comment: Ok, I don't know what is wrong. I have created a new project (django 1.5) and I played with the var LANGUAGE_CODE and USE_L18N, it's work like I expected. I don't know how to help you more :(
(I don't know your code, there may be something wrong in it)